# error:Redirect uri invalid for vimeo using oath in ios app

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, redirect, vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

In my app I'm integrating OAuth2.0 library for vimeo upload. I'm getting error as invalid redirect uri after user log into his account.
My code,

self.oauthClient = [[LROAuth2Client alloc] initWithClientID:@"**** client ID ****"
      secret:@" *** secret *** " redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"testMyApp://oauth"]];

In the plist i have given "testMyApp" as string in url schemes.

is this the right way to specify redirect uri? please help!

Answer (score 2):

Your redirect url must 100% match the url configured on the developer site.

If your user is redirected to `testMyApp://oauth` your configured redirect url must be exactly `testMyApp://oauth`

Answer (score 1):

The 3 pieces of information that you pass back to the Vimeo API (`redirect_uri`, `code`, `grant_type`) must be form URL encoded body parameters.

If they're being passed as query parameters, for example, the request will fail and return the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

For the Vimeo API to allow for your redirect, you have to register it for your app with the [developer site](https://developer.vimeo.com/).  When it is registered there you are able to use it when you specify the redirect.

The plist scheme registration only notifies iOS that you can handle the scheme; Vimeo is unaware that it's a valid thing to redirect to for your app without this step.

Comment: Thanks! But I have registered in developer site. I have given "testMyApp" as redirect url. And in the plist of my app I have given "testMyApp" itself in the URLScheme.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect url in the developer site must exactly match with the one in your application authentication request. I faced the same problem because of difference in the redirect url. But I fixed that and its working.

Developer site redirect url:[image]

My app's request url:

> https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=**vimeo608e5e6ffab5f7d2b567443f57684fdae8f8cb1c://auth**&response_type=code&state=aee5252c-963c-4146-8358-a423326dd03c&scope=private%20public%20create%20edit%20delete%20interact&client_id=608e5e6ffab5f7d2b557443f57684fdae8f8cb1c

the value of the key redirect_url in above request is exact to the developer site. Please feel free to comment..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had forgotten to enable implicit authentication and was getting the `missing redirect_uri` message.

[image]